# Can an NP-search problem be defined non-constructively?

Tags: quantum-computing, np, search-problem, definitions

Given a random two-to-one function $f(x)$ from $n$ bits to $n$ bits, consider the following search problem:

- Find a polynomial number of pairs $(d,y)\in \{0,1\}^n\times\{0,1\}^n$ with $d\ne \bf 0$ such that, for each such pair, there exist preimages $(x_1,x_2)$ with $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$, and also that $d\cdot(x_1\oplus x_2)=0$.

That is, $d$ encodes some information about the $\mathsf{XOR}$ of the two preimages of $y$.  This is a search problem (the decision variant is always trivially true).  Randomly guessing a string $d$ without knowledge of $(x_1,x_2)$ succeeds generically only 50% of the time.

We may require an exponential number of queries to find colliding pairs $(x_1,x_2)$ in order to come up with a string $d$ orthogonal to the $\mathsf{XOR}$ of these preimages.  Furthermore a quantum computer can find such pairs $(d,y)$ easily with measurements in the Hadamard and computational bases (but the quantum computer cannot efficiently find $(x_1,x_2)$, as this would violate the [collision lower bound](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0111102)).

Efficient classical verification can be done with knowledge of $(x_1,x_2,d,y)$ but the problem as framed only asks for $(d,y)$.  My question is, as framed, is this a proper **NP-search** problem?

**QUESTION**  Is NP-search defined non-constructively?  That is, does the definition of NP-search merely require that there *exists* a witness that could efficiently verify the solution?  If so is the problem above a proper oracle separation for NP-search problems between BQP and BPP?  Or must an NP-search problem be defined to require actually finding the specific witness - e.g., all of $(x_1,x_2,d,y)$ and not just $(d,y)$ in the above problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)#Verifier-based_definition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_problem, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/105760/755

Comment: The definition of NP-search problems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNP_(complexity)) requires that the solution can be verified in P, so no, what you wrote is not an NP-search problem.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek thank you for your comment, and I believe you, but it’s not so clear in the links yet. At any rate *what kind of problem* is it to find $(d,y)$ without necessarily finding $(x_1,x_2)$ as well, if it’s not an NP-search problem?

Comment: It’s a projection of an NP-search problem. This class of problems does not have a generally accepted succinct name.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek thanks! I understand and like that phrase. The NP certificate is all of $(x_1,x_2,d,y)$ but the problem only projects on to the last two coordinates $(d,y)$.